# Sort Out Random Numbers into Even and Odd Numbers Using a For Loop

Tags: for-loop, project

I'm in a programming 2 course at my High School and my teacher refuses to teach us and answer questions with straight forward answers. (They are all extremely vague) We always just get projects to past the time and just have to fend for ourselves. The project we have this week is to enter five numbers and using a for loop, (NOT an array) state rather the entered number is even or odd. This is the code I have so far, I took a tip for the "for" line from a friend of mine in a class, so that's probably the problem with the code. (Which is, when I try to run the program it won't get out of the compiling stage)  Thank you so much!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int one = scan.nextInt();
        int two = scan.nextInt();
        int three = scan.nextInt();
        int four = scan.nextInt();
        int five = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            if (one < -1) {
                System.out.println("An Error Has Ocurred.");
            } else {
                if (one % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("This is an even number");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("This is an odd number.");
                }
            }
            if (two < -1) {
                System.out.println("An Error Has Ocurred.");
            } else {
                if (two % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("This is an even number");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("This is an odd number.");
                }
            }
            if (three < -1) {
                System.out.println("An Error Has Ocurred.");
            } else {
                if (three % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("This is an even number");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("This is an odd number.");
                }
            }
            if (four < -1) {
                System.out.println("An Error Has Ocurred.");
            } else {
                if (four % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("This is an even number");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("This is an odd number.");
                }
            }
            if (four < -1) {
                System.out.println("An Error Has Ocurred.");
            } else {
                if (four % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("This is an even number");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("This is an odd number.");
                }
            }
            if (five < -1) {
                System.out.println("An Error Has Ocurred.");
            } else {
                if (five % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("This is an even number");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("This is an odd number.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this.
`

```
import java.util.*;

public class Project {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int number = scan.nextInt();
            if ((number & 1) == 0) {
                System.out.println(number + " is Even");
            } else {
                System.out.println(number + " is Odd");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Give input as 10 15 64 68 75

```
Output:
10 is Even
15 is Odd
64 is Even
68 is Even
75 is Odd
```

Comment: Just as a suggestion, it is generally a good idea not to give a finished solution, but rather guiding instructions or participate in a discussion, when questions about a student assignment is asked. This lets the student find the answer himself/herself while you are a part of their learning experience.

Comment: I tried this code out and it won't get out of the compiling stage, (Which was the same problem with my original code) any idea in what's wrong?

Comment: What are the compilation errors and what do you think they mean?

Comment: I don't know, BlueJ (The executor program that we use) says the syntax is all correct so I'm guessing a logic error?

Comment: If you don't get any compilation errors when you compile, then it's not a problem with the 'compilation stage'. Please make a new question in which you describe your current code, the errors you receive (what do you observe that makes you realize that it isn't working as you expect, **this is important**) and what you have tried to solve the errors. Please do edit your question here, or add a comment, linking to the new question, making it more likely for those of us who have shown interest to find your new question.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea what is wrong with it, that's why I turned to this site. I have been looking at this code for about two days now and I have simply no idea why it won't compile and run.

Comment: I think you should copy the same code and run it on online platform like [link]http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php and check if its working there. If it works online then there must be problem with your interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add the parameter `String[] args` to the `main method`.
The java main method is look like this: `public static void main(String args[])`.

Second you don't need to this code to do something like you want. You only need to read [the java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/) and to have an researcher esprit.

Comment: Okay, I just changed it. Though, since the executor program that I'm using doesn't prefer either main() or main(String args[]) it didn't change anything. The program still won't compile.